# Voting application - OOP

Tags: python, object-oriented

I am developing an API and I have some questions about variables from another class. Here is an example (reduced code to be more assertive):

File user.py

```
from ..db_func import *
from flaks import jsonify

class User():
    def __init__ (self, P_id_user = None, P_login = None, P_nome = None):
        self.id_user = P_id_user
        self.login = P_login
        self.nome = P_nome

    @property
    def id_user(self):
        return self._id_user
    
    @id_user.setter
    def id_user(self, value):
        self._id_user = value 

    @property
    def login(self):
        return self._login
    
    @login.setter
    def login(self, value):
        self._login = value 

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self._nome
    
    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, value):
        self._nome = value 

    #user functions here
```

File campaign.py

```
from ..db_func import *
from .vote import *
from ..uac.classes.groups import *

class Campaign():
    def __init__ (self, P_id_campaign = None, P_name_campaign = None, P_description = None):
        self.id_campaign = P_id_campaign
        self.name_campaign = P_name_campaign
        self.description = P_description

    @property
    def id_campaign(self):
        return self._id_campaign
    
    @id_campaign.setter
    def id_campaign(self, value):
        self._id_campaign = value 

    @property
    def name_campaign(self):
        return self._name_campaign
    
    @name_campaign.setter
    def name_campaign(self, value):
        self._name_campaign = value 

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description
    
    @description.setter
    def description(self, value):
        self._description = value 

    #campaign functions here
```

File vote.py

```
from .campaign import *
from ..db_func import *

class Vote(Campaign):
    def __init__ (self, P_id_vote = None, P_description = None):
        self.id_vote= P_id_vote
        self.description = P_description

    @property
    def id_vote(self):
        return self._id_vote
    
    @id_vote.setter
    def id_vote(self, value):
        self._id_vote = value  

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description
    
    @description.setter
    def description(self, value):
        self._description = value 

    def insert_vote(self, id_campaign, vote): #vote is a JSON
        self.id_campaign = id_campaign
        self.description = vote['description_vote']
        id_user = vote['user']

        self.id_vote = db().execute_query('insert into tb_vote (id_campaign, desc, id_user) values (%s, %s, %s)'), [self.id_campaign, self.description, id_user]
        return jsonify({'mensagem' : 'Success!', 'data' : 'Vote computed!', 'id_vote' : self.id_vote}), 201

    # other vote functions here
```

Routes.py

```
from .classes.campaign import *
from .classes.vote import *
from ...uac.classes.user import *
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required
from . import cadastro
from flask import request

@cadastro.get('/campaign')
@jwt_required()
def get_campaigns(subdomain):
    return Campaign().get_campaigns()
#example of route

@cadastro.post('/campaign/<id_campaign>/votes')
@jwt_required()
def create_campaign_vote(id_campaign):
    json_vote = request.get_json()
    if not json_vote:
        return jsonify({'mensagem' : 'Error!', 'data' : 'Invalid payload!'}), 400
    return Vote().insert_vote(id_campaign, json_vote)
# The route of the question
```

I have three classes: `User`, `Campaign` and `Vote`. With these three classes, I call an endpoint(/api/campaigns/<id_campaign>/votes) to insert the user's vote in a campaign; the `id_user` is sent in the application generated JSON.

**Question**: Is using `id_user = vote['user']` (without `self`) in the `insert_vote` function a good practice in OOP? Do I need to extend `User` or simply declare the `self.id_user` in `Vote` class?

I am learning OOP and declarations and references of this type are new to me. I didn't found any example like this to use as reference or help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do neither but rather go with an MVC architecture if you are using Flask.

Here's an example I wrote a while back that's dated but has the pattern:
https://github.com/cdennison/flask-rest-example/blob/master/flask_rest_api/problems/views.py

Or Google MVC architecture and get something like this:
https://plainenglish.io/blog/flask-crud-application-using-mvc-architecture

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain why a Model View Controller design pattern would help, since the user is a beginner

Comment: MVC architecture will solve my problem since SQLAlchemy will handle all classes and functions. I'll test it, if solved, I'll accept as answer.